# CQ5 - Cancel individual property inheritance of a Live Copy component

Tags: aem

Does anyone know how to configure a CQ component so that each property can be cancelled individually inside of a Live Copy? I am trying to have it set up the same way as the Page Properties, so that canceling one property does not break inheritance for all of them.

**Page Properties:**

[image: Page Property]

**Component Properties:**

[image: Page Property]

The only difference that I'm noticing is the mixin types on the respective jcr:content nodes.

**Page Mixins:**

cq:PropertyLiveSyncCancelled
cq:LiveRelationship

**Component Mixins:**

cq:LiveSyncCancelled
cq:LiveRelationship

I've even tried manually setting the cq:PropertyLiveSyncCancelled Mixin for the component in the content along with ["jcr:description"], but CQ is ignoring this directive entirely.

Does anyone know how this could be done? Thanks!

Comment: I've asked Adobe and they said that it is a known bug as of 5.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add "fieldEditLockMode" property with value "true" to your component dialog to enable cancelling of individual properties inheritance:

[image: set fieldEditLockMode to true]

[image]

It works for AEM 6.0.

Comment: Great, thanks. Just logged in after 5 years. How did you find out about that? I don't see that documented anywhere on Adobe's site nor the Widget API. Working in AEM has been terrible. Adobe stinks.

Comment: Actually I don't remember how I found it. Probably somewhere in OOTB components. Yes, It happens very often with AEM when documentation is absent and you have to inspect their code to understand how a feature  should work.

Answer (score 1):

On the livecopy you can cancel property inheritance with the following:

```
<jcr:content
    jcr:mixinTypes="[cq:LiveSync]"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:PageContent"
    sling:resourceType="project/pages/homepage"
    insertCode="FG"
    cq:propertyInheritanceCancelled="[insertCode]" />
```

If the **insertCode** property is present in the blueprint it wont be copied over to the livecopy nor created if not present on the livecopy - entirely ignored.